# Scala Play: how to add a github library to the project (securesocial)

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, dependency-management, securesocial

I'm new to Scala and to Play.
I'm trying to setup https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial which is a Play project implementing a login/registration component for a website.
Unfortunately this project doesn't have a password strength validator built in (unless you provide your own password validator, the registration process only checks for Password length, not strength).
So I'd like to add my own password validator using the following library:

https://github.com/tekul/szxcvbn

I cloned https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial

I can use `sbt` to build and run the project. How should I proceed to add https://github.com/tekul/szxcvbn as a dependency ? I think there must be a better way than to copy/paste the source of one project into the other.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Maven Central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/eu.tekul/szxcvbn) lists the dependency as

```
libraryDependencies += "eu.tekul" %% "szxcvbn" % "0.2"
```

To import it to `securesocial` you would add  it to `securesocial/build.sbt` like so:

```
lazy val root = project.in( file(".") ).aggregate(core, scalaDemo, javaDemo) .settings(
     aggregate in update := false,
     libraryDependencies += "eu.tekul" %% "szxcvbn" % "0.2"
   )
```

However, I believe `szxcvbn` cannot be imported into `securesocial` out-of-the-box because  `securesocial` was built for [Scala 2.11.x upwards](https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial/blob/b2c9b17bc6b85e2c1341bef43ba765fa2e970bca/project/Common.scala#L7), while the latest version of Scala `szxcvbn` was built against is only [2.9.x](https://github.com/tekul/szxcvbn/blob/ad12689b52448e215fab22c4a15a9257df9f24b9/project/Build.scala#L20). You would first have to figure out how to build `szxcvbn` for 2.11.x upwards.

Comment: Thanks! Since this Scala version mismatch prevents the build, I think I'll run a small rest service in python that does the strength evaluation part. But thanks for your reply. I'll certainly come back read this when I need to include dependencies on another library.

Comment: You can import Java libraries in Scala projects. Try [nbvcxz](https://github.com/GoSimpleLLC/nbvcxz): `"me.gosimple" % "nbvcxz" % "1.4.1"`

Comment: It worked like a charm using the Java library. Thanks again!